Reverse for 'service' not found . template base.html, error at line 0 why i am getting this error?

i have created services.html in templates and also defined a view for it and url in urls.py but then i decided to simply remove it because i don't need it i deleted my template services.html and also view and url from urls.py but i am getting this error even i don't have any veiw name services or url in my urls.py but still i am getting this error during template rendering error at line 0.
This is views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render



def home(request):
   return render(request,'webapp/home.html')

urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
 path('',views.home,name='home'),
 ]

urls.py Project
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('',include('webapp.urls')),

]

project structure:


first i have removed all url tags in my templates and still i getting that error then i check my other template which i am extending from base.html there i missed that {% url 'services' %} i just removed it and error is gone.
